# Algorithm for ropes touching poles

Tags: algorithm

You have a number of poles of different heights, evenly spaced apart, and a rope that runs across the tops of them. The rope is stretched tight and does not sag. Obviously the rope does not necessarily touch the tops of all the poles - if a pole is shorter than the two on either side of it, for example, then the rope will never touch that pole.

How do we find which poles touch the rope and which don't?

I've been told there is an algorithm for this faster than n-squared.

(Not homework)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basically the [convex hull problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms). (The polygon vertices are the tops of all the poles and the bottoms of the first and last poles.) The linked Wikipedia page gives several algorithms that are better than O(n<sup>2</sup>). The best seem to be [marriage-before-conquest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkpatrick%E2%80%93Seidel_algorithm) and [Chan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chan%27s_algorithm), both of which are O(n log h) where n is the number of poles (+2) and h is the number of poles that the rope will actually touch (also +2).

Actually, if the poles are already sorted by x coordinate, the [Graham scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) and the [Monotone Chain](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain) algorithms are O(n).